The API is down
As of 2024-08-14 21:17:15 UTC, the API appears to be fully dead, and blocked by CloudFlare. This is limited to specifically the API; no other services appear to be down.
I've verified this on my IP, a VPN, and two other people on different IPs (and different countries) have also confirmed. SmokeDetector and the SOBotics bots are also dead, most likely as a result of whatever this is.

@Slate There are more bugs still. Making any API calls (read: one singular API call) immediately triggers "too many requests"

Norepro here. You're certain it's a general issue?

@Slate reproduced on my first API request in weeks

@Slate Down for me. I can also give you a Cloudflare ray if needed.

@Slate SD is still dead, the comment archive died immediately after  the first API call, and other users have verified. I got blocked on my home network, hopped on a VPN where I wasn't, made a single call to /answers, refreshed, and got blocked.

Passed it along, thanks

I show a lot of errors in my log, but as of 5-6 minutes ago it's working again.

Twofer issue. We've mitigated the second issue, and the API should again be stable.
